# Domain Name - IP address with IE

Tags: apache, web, dns, html

I have the interesting situation.

Intranet website with a domain name for example  abc.edu and IP address 10.20.10.100

Web server Apache 2.

Web browser IE 11. If I use DNS name the web page displaying incorrectly

[image]

If IP Address everything is fine.
[image]

For all other browsers  Firefox and Chrome. DNS name working fine.

Any Ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Pretend IE doesn't exist? :D

Comment: How do you define the path to your assets? Fire the dev console in IE and check for security warnings.

Comment: /var/www/html/login.php                                                                                                                 
 /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.20.10.100    abc.edu

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved very simply, [image] uncheck Display intranet sites in Compatibility View.

Comment: I have also similar problem and resolved it by unchecking check boxes, but It works in some machine and not in another. Any other workaround ?